# Using google cam to make horizontal 180-degree fisheye pics

Tags: camera, nexus-5, gyroscope

On my Nexus 5, I'd like to use the google camera in panorama mode to make a 180-degree fisheye photo. I want to do this holding my phone in such a way that the lens is looking UPWARDS (towards the sky). In other words, my zenith should be in the middle of the final processed picture. Unfortunately, I can only create fisheyes when I hold the phone in an upright position, i.e. when it is aligned to the horizon. This means that by the end of the whole process, I am going to have a final image showing half terrain, half sky.

When I hold my phone horizontally,thus looking upwards, before starting the capturing process an arrow appears that forces me to put it in a vertical position - aligned with the horizon - before it creates the first pic. See here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Xl49qe9PWbYk5lcXA2czY4aDg/view?usp=sharing

The reason why I want to do this is because I'd like to put this picture on a planetarium dome. These domes represent the sky above us and therefore show mostly sky and not terrain.

Here's an example pic of what I want to create: http://www.philohome.com/skycollec/original/sky11.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. To take the panoramic photo you need to move the camera around anyway, because you don't really have a fisheye lens. Why can't you just start in the suggested position and make sure you include upward-pointing shots as well as the horizon ones?

Comment: The camera app wants me to start in such a way that by the end of the capturing process (37 images) I have the upper half of the final image showing the sky and the bottom half showing terrain. It won't let me with I hold my phone in a horizontal position. There is an arrow showing up on the display that requires me to move/tilt my phone in such a way that it is aligned with the horizon again. Then, and only then, the capturing starts. Here's a screenshot with the arrow pointing down https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Xl49qe9PWbYk5lcXA2czY4aDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The best description of what I actually want: I want my sky zenith in the middle of the final image and not the horizon!

Comment: I don't think the projection that these panoramas use is suitable for that kind of image. You either want a "photosphere" or a different camera app.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, I can't fine a way to do it either. The app wants to force me to have the centre of the fisheye image "horizontal".